# Preparing a JSP page for working with database entries

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to make a page where you can search the database for gigs, if you press enter, it shows all gigs, and after each gig you have buttons EDIT and DELETE, where I will add the correct functionality.

I am so far testing with a printout of which button I am pressing, and seeing if the ID field gets transfered correctly. If I search for a specific gig, and then on that result, click one of the buttons, it does show me the correct EDIT 3, DELETE 2
For example, depending on which gig it was. But, when the whole page is up showing all gigs, and I press a button on any gig, I always get EDIT 1, DELETE 1 printed, so it always sets the ID to 1, no matter which one I clicked.

```
    <%
if(request.getAttribute("gigs")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("searchGig");
    return;
}
%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="bean.Gig"%>
<jsp:useBean id="gigs" type="java.util.ArrayList<Gig>" scope="request" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Gigplanner</title>
<link href="gigplanner.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


<form id="msform" action="searchGig" method="post">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li><a href="index.jsp">Front Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="addGig.jsp">Add Gig</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="searchGig.jsp">Search Gigs</a></li>
    <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>


<fieldset>
Search Gig: 
<input type="text" name="hakusana" value="" >
<input type="submit" class="show-button" value="Search" >
<br>
<div class="showgig">

<%

for(int i=0;i<gigs.size();i++){
        out.print("<table>");

        out.print("<tr><td>Title:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getTitle()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>Venue:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getVenue()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>Date:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getDate()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>Time:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getTime()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>Country:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getCountry()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>Address:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getAddress()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>Postcode:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getPostcode()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>City:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getCity()+ "</td>"));

        out.print("<tr><td>Description:");
        out.print("<td>" +(gigs.get(i).getDescription()+ "</td>"));

      out.print("<input type='hidden' name='id' value="+(gigs.get(i).getId()+">"));  
      out.print("<tr><td><input type='submit' name='act' class='show-button' value='edit'></td>");
      out.print("<td><input type='submit' name='act' class='show-button' value='delete'></td>");

        out.print("</tr></table><br>"); 
  }

String act = request.getParameter("act");
String id = request.getParameter("id");
if (act == null) {
    //no button has been selected
} else if (act.equals("delete")) {
    //delete button was pressed
    out.print("DELETE " + Long.valueOf(id));


} else if (act.equals("edit")) {
    //edit button was pressed
    out.print("EDIT " + Long.valueOf(id));
    } else {
    //something else
}


%>
</div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  <br />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should have avoided use of all this out.print. Jsp is a view technology. Refactor your code to be it like html and may be your error rectify itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `getParameter()` method of the request object relies on the name of the html element which **may be common to many html elements**.

In your case the method fetches the first element with that name associated to it without considering the others.

When you search for a specific gig you have probably only one element on the page therefore there's no way to get the ID wrong, while when all of them are on the page you are not getting the expected result.

You should use `getParameterValues()` and then find a way to retrieve the specific value you are interested in (for instance by using *check-boxes* associated to each gig, each of which would have the same name attribute but different value) or create a `form` element for each gig.